# In how many ways can 8 people be seated in a row of 30 chairs, such that no 2 people sit next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

My attempt:

If no 2 people can sit next to each other then I can take 1 people and 2 chairs as 1 unit. So the first person has 15 choices where to sit, second has 14, third has 13 and so on.. Until the eighth person has 15-7 choices.

$${15! \over (15-8)!} = {15! \over 7!}$$

Am I doing it right? I have a feeling that there is something more to it..

Comment: If you apply your reasoning to $2$ people and $4$ chairs, you get ${2!\over(2-2)!}={2!\over0!}=2$.  But clearly there are at least $4$ ways to seat the two people, since person A can sit in any of the four chairs and person B can always find somewhere to sit. (In fact there are $6$ possible seatings.) In short, it can help to check what your reasoning says about *smaller* cases where it's easy to see if it gives the right answer.

Comment: @BarryCipra You are right! I should have checked whether it works on smaller numbers.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line up the eight people in some order, say alphabetically.  Hand each of them a chair.  That leaves $22$ chairs.  Line up those $22$ chairs in a row. This creates $23$ spaces, $21$ between successive chairs and $2$ at the ends of the row, in which a person can insert a chair.  To ensure that the people are separated, each person must place his or her chair in a separate space.  The first person has $23$ options, which leaves $22$ options for the next person, and so forth.  Hence, the number of permissible seating arrangements is 
$$23 \cdot 22 \cdot 21 \cdot 20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16 = 23 \cdot 22 \cdot 21 \cdot 20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16 \cdot \frac{15!}{15!} = \frac{23!}{15!}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Combinatorics has always been a problem for me, but you explained it very well, and I think I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Place the $8$ people in a line, and **give them chairs**. This can be done in $8!$ ways. Now give the first $7$ people a chair to place on their right, so that now we have $8$ people which are separated by chairs.

There are $9$ gaps created between these people with their chairs, in which we are to insert $30 - 7 - 8 = 15$ more chairs. This can be done in ${15 + 9 - 1 \choose 15} = {23 \choose 15}$ ways.

Thus the answer is $8! {23 \choose 15}$ ways.

---

Note: In general, $k$ out of $n$ objects can be chosen (allowing for repetition) in ${n + k - 1 \choose k}$. This is sometimes called [multichoose](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html).

Comment: Sorry, but this still doesn't look right to me.  You seem to have left the $8$ people *standing*! What happens if you happen to put the final $23$ chairs all at one end? Where are the people supposed to sit?

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  If we place eight people with a chair between any two successive people, we have used $15$ chairs, so we have to place $15$ more chairs in the nine spaces.

Comment: @BarryCipra You're right - I left them standing! Poor people. Change the $23$ to $15$ and the answer becomes $8!{23\choose 15}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I edited and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Align people in a row.
Put one chair between any two consecutive people. So you have 23 chairs left. You must choose 8 of them to sit down 8 people. That is ${23\choose 8}$. Now of course you can permute them. So the final answer is ${23!\over 15!}$

Comment: I see someone downvoted. If that person would say why a would appreciate that.